# Spring MVC Form - Long and String value. The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Simply example, check it

Entity (USER, MOBILEPHONE)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User {

private Long id
private String name;
private Set<Mobilephone> mobilephones= new HashSet<mobilephones>(0);

public User(Long id)
 this.id = id
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public Long getId() {
   return this.id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

//getter and setter for name

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
public Set<Mobilephone> getMobilephones() {
    return this.mobilephones;
}

public void setMobilephones(Set<Mobilephone> mobilephones) {
    this.mobilephones= mobilephones;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "MOBILEPHONE")
public class Mobilephone {

private Long id
private Long number;
private User user

public MobilePhone(Long id)
 this.id = id
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public Long getId() {
   return this.id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

//getter and setter for number

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "USERID", nullable = false)
public User getUser() {
    return this.user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user= user;
}
```

Webpage

```
<form:form modelAttribute="mobilephoneAttribute" action="url" method="post">
   <form:input path="mobilephone"/>
   <form:select path="user">
        <c:forEach items="${userlist}" var="user">
            <form:option value="${user.id}" label="${user.telephone" />
        </c:forEach>
   </form:select>
   <input type="submit"/>
</form:form>
```

Whats happening.

After submit i get this error:

```
The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.
```

**If I change my User: "Long id" to "String id" (and also methods) the problem disappears.**

I thought at the beginning, spring has a problem with the convert Long to String?
But probably not, because we have a number where Long is saved with no problems.

Someone knows the problem?

Comment: try using <form:select path="user.id">

Comment: can you see any error in server logs ?

Comment: @ankur-singhal No this is not happening! it works! Thanks mate

Comment: @user2363971 i did not get you, using this `<form:select path="user.id"> ` does it works

Comment: @user2363971 answer posted for your acceptance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using

```
<form:select path="user.id"> 
        <c:forEach items="${userlist}" var="user">
            <form:option value="${user.id}" label="${user.telephone" />
        </c:forEach>
   </form:select>
```